# what is the different between tuple & record and files & pages & blocks in term of DBMS?

Tags: database, tuples, records

what is the different  between tuple & record and file & pages & blocks in term of DBMS? I am really confused lecturer mention all of this together , and what its job each one of them.

Comment: Consider accepting the answers that helped you solve the problem, that is how SO works ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of a "tuple" pertains to the logical level.  The concept of a "record" pertains to the physical/implementation level.  The concept of a "tuple" is specific for relational DB technology in particular.  The concept of a "record" was already well-known to IT people in the time when DB technology still had to be invented.

The concept of a "file" pertains to the level of a file management system, which is typically a high-level component of any OS.  The concept of a "block" pertains to the level of *device* management systems, which are often not even a component of the OS, but rather of the BIOS (thus the concept is "lower-level" than "files").  The concept of a "page" is probably not as exactly and formally defined as some may want it to be.  To my mind, it can stand for anything from "just a synonym for 'block'" over "some fixed number n of blocks with n>1" to "just any arbitrary number of blocks".

Comment: I like this answer from a database-implementation (IE, you are writing a DB) point of view because it clarifies that for things like pages, you probably ought to refer to values as "record" because it's a physical thing, whereas in your query execution code then maybe "tuple" is more relevant. Or you could just pick one and use them in both places I guess.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion:

#### tuple and record

`tuple` and `record` are synonyms, which mean one row of related table. Perhaps `tuple` is more academic in DBMS and `record` is more daily.

#### files

`files` are some data files that contain any information about your database.

e.g.

In `PostgreSQL` database, if you create a database named `company`, then in your file system, `company` would be a directory (the directory name is not `company` but it's `id` like `11343`).

After that, if you create a table named `employee` in `company`. The `PostgreSQL` will create a `employee` file(also use its id as name) under the `company` directory.

And if you insert some tuples/records in `employee`, the data will be written into `employee` file.

#### pages and blocks

`pages` and `blocks` are also synonyms. But `pages` is used in DBMS view and `blocks` is used in OS view.

e.g.

There are some tuples in table `employee`. But tuples are first contained in `pages` and then `pages` are contained in `employee` file. Like this [picture](https://www.interdb.jp/pg/img/fig-1-04.png).

As you can see, `pages` and `blocks` are the some thing.

Answer (score 0):

In DBMS

A Tuple is a Single row of Table.
A Block is a column(entity) in a Table.
A Relational Instance is a Finite Set Of Tuples.

Answer (score -1):

[1]Tuple v/s Row

In context it is different words to mean exactly the same thing.

Tuple, means an ordered list with possibly repeated elements compare to a set, which has all unordered list.

Example of tuple : (1,5)

Example of record : { "a" : 1, "b" : 5}

[2]Defintion of File/Block/Page

File : A physical file on disk which is created by Database and contains the data for a database. The data files can be located either in an operating system file system.

Block : It is the smallest unit of data that an operating system can either write to a file or read from a file.

Page : A page is basically a virtual block having fixed length of 2KB or 4KB.